# Flask, session data not accessible on some routes?

Tags: python, flask, session

I'm trying to store some session data for the user, such as the username. I am able to set the username to the session on my "/setUser" route, and access the data via "/getUser", however, in my "/loginUser" route, it says it's set it to the session, but I cannot get the data to update to the new session username on the "/getUser" route.

Here's the code:

/loginUser - A snippet where it sets session data

```
# Fetch the result
userData = dbCommand.fetchone()

print(userData)

# If we get a match, we have a successful login
if userData:
    # Create session data so we can access it on other routes
    session['username'] = 'admin'
    print("SAVED SESSION VALUE: " + session.get('username'))
    print("LOGGED IN!")


    return jsonify({"success": True})
```

/setUser

```
@userFunctions.route("/setUser")
def dbTest():
    session['username'] = 'Test User'
    return 'Session data stored'
```

/getUser

```
@userFunctions.route("/getUser", methods=["GET"])
def getCurrUser():
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        print("Session modified: " + str(session.modified))
        return username
    else:
        return "Not found"
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Environment: VSCode, Windows 11.

Tried using regular flask sessions, as well as Flask-Session library. No success either way.

Comment: Have you imported `from flask import session` in the loginUser file ?